# How do I check whether I'm Internet2 routable?

Tags: networking, internet, routing

How do I check whether I have access to/am accessible from [Internet2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Internet2)? [Google says](http://k20.internet2.edu/faq) I should be using Internet2 Detective, but that tool seems to have disappeared.

The host is at an institution that is an Internet2 member. However, the network admins are not sufficiently competent to reliably route over Internet2 when possible. So how would you empirically test Internet2 connectivity?

Comment: Maybe this will be of some use: http://www.internet2.edu/performance/ndt/ndt-server-list.html
 Try one of the host links and see if it let's you through. (Didn't let me through, but then again I don't have access to Internet2)

Comment: @Leathe Some initial testing lead me to think those might be Internet2 only hosts. However, I have a AWS EC2 server that can access at least one of those servers, and I'm was sure AWS is not Internet2 enabled. Or maybe it is? http://www.internet2.edu/news/pr/2013.04.23.amazon-web-services-internet2.html

Comment: You are correct, the Internet2 Detective software has gone the way of the dodo.

Answer (score 5):

So the first question I would ask is "why do you want to know?"  What capability do you think you will get from Internet2 that you wouldn't get otherwise?  Not to say that you don't get anything special, but in general, if you are asking this question, you may not need it.

With that in mind, here's an answer to the question you asked.

In general, there are very few Internet2-only hosts; most everything that is Internet2-connected is also connected to the rest of the Internet.  As it turns out, though, you are correct that the NDT servers on that list are connected to Internet2, without full internet connectivity.

However...AWS & the rest of Amazon is connected to Internet2 via Internet2's TR-CPS "commodity peering service," which connects Internet2 member campuses to large providers, with the goal of reducing their (more expensive) general commodity Internet usage.   So, it's quite possible that you are not on Internet2 per se, but rather that you are connected via some network on TR-CPS.  IIRC even one of the Tier 1 ISPs is connected via TR-CPS, I don't recall which one.

So, we know that if you can't see the NDT servers, you do not have Internet2 connectivity; but if you can see them, that doesn't mean you really *do* have Internet2 in the sense that you are thinking.

One way would be to do a traceroute to a site that is known to be connected to Internet2, and see what path it follows.  www.internet2.edu is a good choice, but here in Michigan I actually connect to it via the regional network, Merit, without traversing the Internet2 network.  so, I'll choose www.stanford.edu, good and far away.  If there is a particular endpoint you're wondering about, well, traceroute to there :).

From umich:

```
%traceroute www.stanford.edu
traceroute to www-v6.stanford.edu (171.67.215.200), 30 hops max, 40 byte packets
 1  v-umce-login.r-aldc-a.umnet.umich.edu (141.211.2.130)  0.325 ms  0.207 ms  0.233 ms
 2  d-aldca-fxb.r-fxb.umnet.umich.edu (198.108.11.160)  0.447 ms  0.322 ms  0.341 ms
 3  l3-arbl-fxb.r-arbl.umnet.umich.edu (141.211.0.137)  0.540 ms  0.419 ms  0.396 ms
 4  l3-barb-rarb.r-bin-arbl.umnet.umich.edu (192.12.80.129)  0.434 ms  0.366 ms  0.341 ms
 5  v-bin-arbl-i2-wsu5.wsu5.mich.net (192.12.80.69)  1.736 ms  1.683 ms  1.739 ms
 6  v0x1004.rtr.wash.net.internet2.edu (192.122.183.10)  29.499 ms  29.475 ms  29.493 ms
 7  ae-8.10.rtr.atla.net.internet2.edu (64.57.28.6)  42.225 ms  42.212 ms  42.217 ms
 8  ae-1.10.rtr.hous.net.internet2.edu (64.57.28.112)  65.631 ms  65.566 ms  65.693 ms
 9  ae-3.10.rtr.losa.net.internet2.edu (64.57.28.96)  96.622 ms  96.470 ms  96.522 ms
10  hpr-lax-hpr--i2-newnet.cenic.net (137.164.26.133)  79.614 ms  79.579 ms  79.715 ms
11  svl-hpr2--lax-hpr2-10g.cenic.net (137.164.25.38)  87.740 ms  87.784 ms  87.745 ms
12  hpr-stanford--svl-hpr2-10ge.cenic.net (137.164.27.62)  88.241 ms  88.283 ms  88.252 ms
13  boundarya-rtr.Stanford.EDU (171.66.0.34)  88.445 ms  88.470 ms  88.446 ms
14  * * *
15  * * *
16  www-v6.Stanford.EDU (171.67.215.200)  88.673 ms  88.674 ms  88.593 ms
```

Here you see my home connection, on comcast.  Turns out it connects via Internet2 TR-CPS, but, again, it's not really "on Internet2" in the sense you are thinking.

```
~@mx-5% traceroute www.stanford.edu
traceroute to www-v6.stanford.edu (171.67.215.200), 64 hops max, 52 byte packets
 1  asus-gw (192.168.1.1)  0.923 ms  0.435 ms  0.396 ms
 2  68.61.232.1 (68.61.232.1)  28.641 ms  28.789 ms  21.431 ms
 3  xe-9-3-0-32767-sur01.sannarbor.mi.michigan.comcast.net (68.85.48.181)  14.523 ms  9.927 ms  10.828 ms
 4  te-0-11-0-3-ar01.pontiac.mi.michigan.comcast.net (69.139.254.89)  16.936 ms
    te-0-9-0-6-ar01.pontiac.mi.michigan.comcast.net (68.85.222.166)  14.810 ms
    te-0-11-0-3-ar01.pontiac.mi.michigan.comcast.net (69.139.254.89)  24.390 ms
 5  he-4-5-0-0-cr01.350ecermak.il.ibone.comcast.net (68.86.90.221)  20.065 ms  25.476 ms  19.849 ms
 6  pos-1-4-0-0-pe01.350ecermak.il.ibone.comcast.net (68.86.86.162)  24.172 ms  21.173 ms  20.791 ms
 7  xe-2-2-0.792.chic0.tr-cps.internet2.edu (137.164.130.237)  19.941 ms  25.691 ms  20.555 ms
 8  xe-0-2-0.0.sttl0.tr-cps.internet2.edu (137.164.129.2)  77.872 ms  72.813 ms  69.914 ms
 9  xe-1-0-0.0.paix0.tr-cps.internet2.edu (64.57.20.222)  79.892 ms  82.818 ms  81.977 ms
10  137.164.131.94 (137.164.131.94)  84.487 ms  81.860 ms  81.483 ms
11  dc-svl-core1--svl-px1-10ge-2.cenic.net (137.164.46.12)  88.455 ms  85.904 ms  87.139 ms
12  dc-svl-agg1--svl-core1-10ge.cenic.net (137.164.47.120)  81.792 ms  81.572 ms  86.826 ms
13  dc-stanford--svl-agg1-10ge.cenic.net (137.164.50.158)  101.479 ms  93.879 ms  82.380 ms
14  boundarya-rtr.stanford.edu (68.65.168.33)  83.739 ms  83.703 ms  84.035 ms
15  * * *
16  * * *
17  www-v6.stanford.edu (171.67.215.200)  83.929 ms  84.631 ms  84.802 ms
```

Disclaimer (or, perhaps, "claimer"): I used to work for Internet2.

Comment: The question that motivates all of this is basically: "Am I getting the highest bandwidth and lowest latencies possible?" The normal answer is, "ask your network admins", but I need to be able to verify what they tell me.

Comment: hope this helps.  Also, be aware that you need to be aware of both network paths - you might take a different return path than your sending path.  The simplest way to do this would be to traceroute in both directions, assuming you can log in to a host on the far end to run traceroute.

Answer (score 0):

The Network Diagnostic Tool at http://www.internet2.edu/performance/ndt/ might also help perform the test (installing which requires applying a kernel patch and appears non-trivial).

FWIW, (untested) source and binaries for Internet2 Detective are available for download at http://www-personal.umich.edu/~bdr/detective/source.html. One of that tool's stated capabilities is "(provides information about) connectivity to an Internet2 backbone network".

Comment: How would it help? I see nothing that indicates that it would check for Internet2 routing.

Comment: setting up an NDT *server* requires a kernel patch, but just about any system can run the NDT client.

Comment: @lid You are correct. I incorrectly assumed that NDT was a replacement for Internet2 Detective before checking it out fully.